# Does every analytic function whose poles don't have a limit point always extend analytically to a meromorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A\subset\mathbb C$ be an open set with nonempty interior and $f:A\to\mathbb C$ be analytic in it. As far as I can tell, two things can happen:

1. $f$ extends analytically to $\mathbb C$ except for possibly a set of isolated points;
2. $f$ extends analytically up to an open set $A_m$, and its poles have a limit point in $\overline{A_m}$. More precisely, the set $\{z_0\in\overline{A_m}:\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty\}$ has a limit point.

Lacunary functions are and the function $f(z)=\sum_{n>0} \frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2\cdot 3^n}} n$ are examples of case 2. The question is: are there any other possibilities, or must 1 or 2 happen every time?

Comment: What about $\log :\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\to\Bbb C$?

Comment: @leoli1 that's a good point. What happens if we want to extend the domain to a Riemann surface instead?

Comment: For any analytic (meromorphic) function in an open set, there is a maximal open set where the function extends analytically (meromorphically) though it may not be unique; not sure exactly what you look for as singularities can be complicated at the boundary if they are not isolated

Comment: @Conrad what do you mean it may not be unique? I think you could post that as an answer.

Comment: For example take $\sqrt z$ on on a small disc centered at $1$ and given by $\sqrt 1=1$; if you pick any Jordan arc connecting $0$ to infinity and not intersecting that disc (could be something simple like a ray and something complicated like a spiral) than you can extend $\sqrt z$ analytically uniquely to the complement of that arc and each such extension is maximal; with a little care you can get such a maximal extension that takes positive and negative values on the positive real axis in infinitely many intervals each

Answer (score 0):

As Leoli and Conrad pointed out in the comments, the unicity I wanted doesn't hold when $f$ has a branch point. I found another counterexample which is more in line with what I wanted (I wasn't very clear) which is

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{(nz-1)^2}.$$

This function has poles at $0$ and the inverse positive integers, but is analytic everywhere else in $\mathbb C$. We could even arrange a function like this whose singularities are spaced in the unit circle in a similar way so that if you tried to expand its domain from the origin, you would find a set of poles with a limit point, and yet $f$ can be extended everywhere else.